# Handling Try Catch for URL in swift3

Tags: swift, image, url, try-catch

My code is here, I would like catch when url link is wrong.

```
 let url = NSURL(string: poster_image_url)
            do{

                let poster_data = try NSData(contentsOf:url! as URL)
                posterImage.image = UIImage(data: poster_data as Data)

            }catch let error {
                debugPrint("ERRor ::\(error)")
            }
```

Didn't catch in my code. How to solve this error? Please help me.

Comment: Why are you using `NSURL`? Why are you casting `Data` to `Data`? Why are you force unwrapping `url` instead of using `if let`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try this code in swift3.0

Code:

```
let url = URL(string: poster_image_url)
do {
    if let url = url {
        let poster_data = try Data(contentsOf:url)
        posterImage.image = UIImage(data: poster_data)
    }
} catch let error {
    debugPrint("ERRor ::\(error)")
}
```

Tip:

1. you should use if-let to unwrap optional value in case of the value is nil.
2. you can use URL(NSURL) and Data(NSData) in swift

Comment: You're welcome, if you have time, you should watch the document of Swift